# What is wrong with invoking `git shortlog` from Go 'exec()'?

Tags: git, go, exec

I'm trying to invoke `git shortlog` from Go to grab the output, but I'm running into a wall.

Here's a working example of how I'm able to do this with `git log`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    runBasicExample()
}

func runBasicExample() {
    cmdOut, err := exec.Command("git", "log").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "There was an error running the git command: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    output := string(cmdOut)
    fmt.Printf("Output: \n%s\n", output)
}
```

Which gives expected output:

```
$>  go run show-commits.go 
Output: 
commit 4abb96396c69fa4e604c9739abe338e03705f9d4
Author: TheAndruu
Date:   Tue Aug 21 21:55:07 2018 -0400

    Updating readme
```

### But I really want to do this with `git shortlog`.

For some reason... I just can't get it to work with shortlog.  Here's the program again, with the only change being the git command line:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    runBasicExample()
}

func runBasicExample() {
    cmdOut, err := exec.Command("git", "shortlog").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "There was an error running the git command: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    output := string(cmdOut)
    fmt.Printf("Output: \n%s\n", output)
}
```

With empty output:

```
$>  go run show-commits.go 
Output:
```

I can run `git shortlog` directly from the command line and it seems to work fine.  Checking the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog), I'm led to believe the 'shortlog' command is part of git itself.

Can anyone help point out what I could do different?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out, I was able to find the answer by re-reading the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog)

The answer was in this line:

> If no revisions are passed on the command line and either **standard input is not a terminal** or there is no current branch, git shortlog will output a summary of the log read from standard input, without reference to the current repository.

Despite the fact that I can run `git shortlog` from the terminal and see expected output, when running via the `exec()` command, I need to specify the branch.

So in the above examples, I added 'master' to the command arguments like so:

```
cmdOut, err := exec.Command("git", "shortlog", "master").Output()
```

And everything works as expected.